# How can I Delete an Item from a Data Grid View and Reflect the Deletion in the MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

**UPDATE**
There has been quite a few changes in the code, but the problem still persists. I was able to delete from the customer table (and the entire row on the DGV) but it does not reach across all the other tables. I followed some advice and added a variable and a DGV click event that points to the customerId in the customer table, but really do not know how to hit the other tables for deletion. I have included the entire class.

Here is the updated code:

```
public partial class DeleteCustomer : Form
    {
        private int selectCustomerID;
         
        public DeleteCustomer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgvLoad();
        }

        private void toLandingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage();
            landingPage.Show();
        }

        private void deleteCustomerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this item?", "Delete Item?",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlKey"].ConnectionString;
                    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                    con.Open();

                    String deleteCustomer = @"DELETE FROM customer 
                                               WHERE customerId = @CUSTOMERID";
                    MySqlCommand customerDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCustomer, con);
                    customerDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTOMERID", selectCustomerID);
                    customerDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String deleteAddress = @"DELETE FROM address 
                                               WHERE addressId = @ADDRESSID";
                    MySqlCommand addressDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteAddress, con);
                    addressDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDRESSID", customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count);
                    addressDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String deleteCountry = @"DELETE FROM country 
                                               WHERE countryId = @COUNTRYID";
                    MySqlCommand countryDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCountry, con);
                    countryDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COUNTRYID", customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count);
                    countryDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String deleteCity = @"DELETE FROM city 
                                               WHERE cityId = @CITYID";
                    MySqlCommand cityDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCity, con);
                    cityDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITYID", customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count);
                    cityDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                    dgvLoad();

                    MessageBox.Show("Customer Deleted", "Complete!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Process Canceled.", "Canceled!");
                }
            }                       
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select at Least One Row.", "Null Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        
        // Adds information from the database to the DGV upon loading
        private void dgvLoad()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlKey"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            String sqlString = @"
                                SELECT customer.customerID, customerName,
                                address.address, address2, postalCode, phone,
                                city.city, country.country
                                FROM country, city, address, customer
                                WHERE customer.addressId = address.addressId 
                                AND address.cityID = city.cityID 
                                AND city.countryId = country.countryId";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable customerDT = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(customerDT);

            customerDeleteDataGridView.DataSource = customerDT;
            customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            customerDeleteDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            con.Close();
        }

        // Clears the selection bar upon loading and until user selects a row
        private void myBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            customerDeleteDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        }


        // DGV click event that points to the customerId cloumn in the DB table
        private void customerDeleteDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                selectCustomerID = (int)customerDeleteDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your patience with me and as always, any help/guidance will be most appreciated.

Comment: Show the table definition in sql. Also where do you get a value of customerId ?
You are using this variable, but not filling with any data. Atleast in attached code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by table definition. customerId is supposed to be the column name in the sql table 'customer' and is the PK.

Answer (score 0):

Replace WHERE **cusomterId** = @CUSTOMERID" to WHERE **customerId** = @CUSTOMERID"

```
String deleteCustomer = @"DELETE FROM customer 
                                           WHERE cusomterId = @CUSTOMERID";
                MySqlCommand customerDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCustomer, con);
                customerDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTOMERID", customerId);
                customerDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that, but the parameter customerId is still getting the error. It seems like it is acting like an undeclared variable instead of the table reference.

Comment: Do you have any releated table like Customer-Order etc. If your customer table have FK, delete this table records first

Comment: I am working this out right now. I will update as soon as I have something more.

Answer (score 0):

After working this for a while and getting some help via a conference call, the problem is fixed. I needed to add the other variables for Address, City and Country then add their row index to the DGV cell click event at the bottom of the class.

Here is the completed, working code:

```
public partial class DeleteCustomer : Form
    {
        private int selectCustomerID;
        private string selectAddressID;
        private string selectCityID;
        private string selectCountryID;

        public DeleteCustomer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgvLoad();
        }

        private void toLandingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage();
            landingPage.Show();
        }

        private void deleteCustomerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this item?", "Delete Item?",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlKey"].ConnectionString;
                    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                    con.Open();

                    String deleteCustomer = @"DELETE FROM customer 
                                               WHERE customerId = @CUSTOMERID";
                    MySqlCommand customerDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCustomer, con);
                    customerDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTOMERID", selectCustomerID);
                    customerDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String deleteAddress = @"DELETE FROM address 
                                               WHERE address = @ADDRESSID";
                    MySqlCommand addressDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteAddress, con);
                    addressDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDRESSID", selectAddressID);
                    addressDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String deleteCity = @"DELETE FROM city 
                                               WHERE city = @CITYID";
                    MySqlCommand cityDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCity, con);
                    cityDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITYID", selectCityID);
                    cityDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String deleteCountry = @"DELETE FROM country 
                                               WHERE country = @COUNTRYID";
                    MySqlCommand countryDelete = new MySqlCommand(deleteCountry, con);
                    countryDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COUNTRYID", selectCountryID);
                    countryDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                    dgvLoad();

                    MessageBox.Show("Customer Deleted", "Complete!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Process Canceled.", "Canceled!");
                }
            }                       
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select at Least One Row.", "Null Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        
        // Adds information from the database to the DGV upon loading
        private void dgvLoad()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlKey"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            String sqlString = @"
                                SELECT customer.customerID, customerName,
                                address.address, address2, postalCode, phone,
                                city.city, country.country
                                FROM country, city, address, customer
                                WHERE customer.addressId = address.addressId 
                                AND address.cityID = city.cityID 
                                AND city.countryId = country.countryId";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable customerDT = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(customerDT);

            customerDeleteDataGridView.DataSource = customerDT;
            customerDeleteDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            customerDeleteDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            con.Close();
        }

        // Clears the selection bar upon loading and until user selects a row
        private void myBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            customerDeleteDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        }

        private void customerDeleteDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                selectCustomerID = (int)customerDeleteDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
                selectAddressID = (string)customerDeleteDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
                selectCityID = (string)customerDeleteDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value;  
                selectCountryID = (string)customerDeleteDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value;
            }

        }
    }
```

This was my first post here and I wanted to thank those who tried to help out and I will work on improving communications.